# Find partial text in range, return cell value

Tags: excel, text, partial

I have an array of data that contains 3 columns and the rows increase as more data gets added. I have some known values such as XX-12345, XXX-12345 or XXXX-12345 that I need to identify and return the content in that cell. The problem is that the naming convention isn't standard, so the value may look like the following: XX-12345-Temp, XX-12345.Temp XXX-12345-Temp, XXX-12345.Temp or XXXX-12345-Temp, XXXX-12345.Temp

Below is the code that I have to perform this function, but it doesn't always work. Sometimes it returns a zero and I cannot figure out why it is doing that.

```
    =INDIRECT("R"&REPLACE(TEXT(MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2,$A$2:$C$15349)),(ROW($A$2:$C$15349))*1000+COLUMN($A$2:$C$15349))),"000000"),4,0,"C"),FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you really need to be involving REPLACE in this construction. You can use:

=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2,$A$2:$C$15349)),10^5*ROW($A$2:$C$15349)+COLUMN($A$2:$C$15349))),"R0C00000"),FALSE)

Regards

Comment: @XOR_LX Yes, that's better!, and presumably 10^5 to accommodate any possible range?

Comment: Indeed, at least whilst there are less than 10^5 columns in a worksheet! Presume this hasn't changed in 2013?

Comment: It hasn't changed yet - http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx?redir=0

Comment: Good! Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thank both of you for the help! I have another question: The Sheet refreshes really slowly since there is so much data and I use a prompt to temporarily open another workbook to copy data. is there any way to speed up the refresh? Within my sub i use the following code already:

Sub CopyData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
- then my code
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

@barryhoudini

Answer (score 0):

That formula will only work up to row 999 because at row 1000 ROW*1000 = 1,000,000 and that will break "000000" in the formula - try this version which will work for ranges up to 99,999 rows

`=INDIRECT("R"&REPLACE(TEXT(MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2,$A$2:$C$15349)),(ROW($A$2:$C$15349))*1000+COLUMN($A$2:$C$15349))),"00000000"),6,0,"C"),FALSE)`

I changed the "000000" to "00000000" and because of that the 4 in REPLACE function needs to be a 6